# how to analyze load on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

It happened to me to create a page to display blog posts.
Every blog entry has the usual "Facebook like", "tweet this post" and "+1". 
There is also some extra JS for other functions and probably some scripts I am not aware of that are running in the background.

The page unfortunately generates a very heavy CPU load, affecting negatively the UX..

I assume that some JS, running in the background, are the cause.

Do you recommend any solution to analyze this kind of problem?
Ideally I would like a "Task manager" for the browser, where I could see WHAT is generating the heavy CPU load.

Comment: I'm using a customized drupal template

Comment: ok, does Drupal have a .net web.config? (sorry im not familiar with it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to analyze it. If call the web page and check it in the fiddler how your webpage performs it is very helpful will tell you which javascript , which image loading takes time. This works for any browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chrome Task manager, it will show you all the statistics you want. Or access memory usage at chrome://system/.

Answer (score 1):

You could use firebug to analyze load of different resource. And also you could use

about:memory

Or try

about:about

and see what 'about:' command you could use to analyze your problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use `YSLOW`(chrome extenstion) to get better insights of your website